# 4-Wheeled Mobile Robot, Motor-Torque, RPM Calculation

Tags: mobile-robot, motor, wheeled-robot, torque

I want the **torque, rpm of every motor** to be used considering certain factors, in a 4 wheeled robot as you see in the picture below.

[image: 4-Wheeled robot(direct shaft-to-wheel coupling)]

Here are the factors affecting motor specifications that I Had taken into account::::

1. **Load = 22 KG**
2. **Wheel Mass = 0.25KG**
3. **Wheel outer Diameter = 0.1 m**
4. **Number of Wheels = 4**
5. **Friction Coefficient = 0.4** *(hard plastic on dry plywood)*
6. **Drive system efficiency = 70%**   *(this is actually from brushed dc motor averages)*
7. **Transmission = Direct coupling**
8. **Floor maximum slope = 10 degrees**
9. **Load holding while the motor is stopped = Yes**
10. **Required robot velocity = 24 m/s**
11. **Required robot Acceleration = 8.8 m/s^(2)**
12. **Number of motors = 4**
13. **Type of wheel = Omni wheel/Normal wheel** *(not sure how you calculate for omni wheels as they have rollers on them)*
14. **Type of Motor = Brushed DC motor**

From online motor sizing tools, I am getting a total torque requirement of 6 nM for the entire system. However, this answer varies from other online resources and my own personal math that I had done.
I also tried to take into the type of wheel to be used as a factor but the I am unsure of the math involving Omni wheels and their load.

**Can someone shed some light on Getting the torque and rpm for motors in this system, on normal wheels and on Omni wheels if possible?**

If anyone has any papers or did similar math for getting these values, kindly share your workings if possible, it will be of great help.
Also I apologize if this is a wrong stack exchange to post as it can be considered a borderline Physics question.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this still helps you, you can try here:

https://www.societyofrobots.com/RMF_calculator.shtml

https://www.orientalmotor.com/motor-sizing/index.html

https://www.maxongroup.de/medias/sys_master/8819062800414.pdf?attachment=true

(Page 23, Sorry it is in german but it has everything for estimations.)

Load holding when the motor stops: I think without brakes you will need self-locking gears.

You should use rolling resistance instead of friction. https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/rolling-friction-resistance-d_1303.html